# Is phonegap application deployed and controlled by phonegap server or can it be deployed locally?

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-plugins

There are different ways of deploying a PhoneGap application. I am just wondering if all of these are controlled by phonegap server? If yes, doesn't it mean we are sharing enterprise data with third party?

Is there any way we can host and deploy the app locally so that no code is shared with phonegap server community?

Comment: PhoneGap application runs in your phone, a.k.a. locally.

Comment: We need not submit anything to phonegap server or the server community..??!

Comment: (facepalm) have you read the mechanism of PhoneGap / Cordova? PhoneGap apps are written in HTML , CSS and JavaScript, but it doesn't represent it is "hosted" in PhoneGap server. The files are still in your phone.

Comment: oops..sorry..was confused with " the cloud-based PhoneGap Build service to compile apps". thanks for the correction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment above, PhoneGap apps are written in HTML , CSS and JavaScript, but it doesn't represent it is "hosted" in PhoneGap server. The files are still in your phone.

Not to be confused with [PhoneGap Build service](https://build.phonegap.com/).